Close family match-help!
I share 1326 cms over 21 segments with a paternal family member, with the longest being 174cm.
Ancestry tells me this is a grandmother (impossible as this person is still living), an auntie or a half sibling.
My dad has a brother 8 years older than him and my dads mother died a few days after my dad was born, so an auntie seems unlikely.
Do the longest segment (174cm) mean an auntie is the most likely possibility?

Will you refine that exposition, please?
When Ancestry tells you someone is a grandmother, what difference could the fact of her still being living make?

According to DNA Painter, a niece/nephew relationship is also possible. The best way to determine how this person is related to you is their age in relation to yours, and talking to them to figure out how you might be connected. Find out where they were born, grew up, what they were told about their origins. This isn't something that can be worked out from DNA alone. Also an aunt cannot be ruled out entirely- she may have been born prior to your uncle.
